# Evaluating multiple conditions at once using PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to change this code sample so that all these conditions are evaluated at the same time. If more than one condition is true multiple arguments can be passed to the 'signup' function.

I originally tried using switch, but each condition needs to be able to evaluate a different condition.

Any help pointing me in the right direction on this would be great.

```
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->signup();

    } else if ($this->membership_model->check_field('username',$this->input->post('username'))) {

        $this->signup("An account with the username you've entered already exists.");

    } else if ($this->membership_model->check_field('email_address',$this->input->post('email_address'))) {

        $this->signup("An account with the e-mail you've entered already exists.");

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put all errors/faulty conditions in an array and pass that to `$this->signup()`.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
    $this->signup();
} 
else 
{
   $errors = array();
   if ($this->membership_model->check_field('username',$this->input->post('username'))) 
       $errors[]= "An account with the username you've entered already exists.";
   if ($this->membership_model->check_field('email_address',$this->input->post('email_address')))
       $errors[]= "An account with the e-mail you've entered already exists.";

   $this->signup($errors);
}
```

Comment: You could also check out [setting form validation errors](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#settingerrors).

Comment: Thx. This looks like a good approach. Using func_get_args(); in the signup function, when the errors array is passed will each item in the read an individual argument or as a single array.

Comment: You should check the docs for that or just test it out (with var_dump() for example).  You could also give signup() a parameter to begin with.  Seems weird to use func_get_args() there.

Comment: Thx -- this makes perfect sense. I was asking because I'm going to probably add a callMessage() function in addition to signup() function.

Answer (score 0):

Use the && operator

a = 1;
b = 2;
if (a == 1 && b == 2) {
    echo "this would show up on the page";
}

Comment: That would work except the results are different for each condition. Also they don't all need to be true.

Comment: Gotcha - I didn't notice the small changes